# htmlunit - Get new page after excuting a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, htmlunit

I have an HtmlPage by WebClient. This page (HtmlPage) has a button, I want to click that button to get a new page (another page). But when I clicked that button, the result returned the same page with the original page. Below is my code:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class GetLink2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("https://fptshop.com.vn/");

    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0";
    WebRequest request = new WebRequest(url);
    request.setAdditionalHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
    //request.setAdditionalHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0");
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);

    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(20000);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);

    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);

    for (DomElement input : page.getElementsByTagName("input")) {
        if (input.getAttribute("placeholder").contains("tìm") ||
                input.getAttribute("placeholder").contains("Tìm")) {
            System.out.println(input.asXml());
            System.out.println("Set element focused: " + page.setFocusedElement(input));

            input.setAttribute("id", "my_input_search");
            System.out.println("Element focused: " + page.getFocusedElement());

            //pageResult = page.pressAccessKey((char) DOM_VK_RETURN).getHtmlPageOrNull().getUrl();
            //System.out.println("Result: " + pageResult.toString());
            //System.out.printf("Result: %s%n", input.fireEvent(String.valueOf(KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_RETURN)).getJavaScriptResult().toString());
            break;
        }

        //System.out.println(htmlElement.asXml());

        //result.getNewPage();
        //System.out.println("result: "+ result.getNewPage().getUrl());
    }


    System.out.println("Input search: " + page.getElementById("my_input_search"));

    String jsScript = "var element = document.getElementById('my_input_search');" +
            "element.value = 'iphone 7';" +
            "element.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {" +
            "console.log(e.key, e.char, e.keyCode)});" +
            "var e = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {" +
            "bubbles: true, cancelable: true, char: 'Enter',key: 'enter', keyCode: 13});" +
            "element.dispatchEvent(e);";

    System.out.println("Input Search After Set Value: " + page.getElementById("my_input_search"));
    page.executeJavaScript(jsScript);
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    page.getPage();
    System.out.println("Result " + page.getPage());
}
}
```

Can everyone help me please, thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Looks like you misunderstand how HtmlUnit works. Have a look at the samples on the HtmlUnit homepage to get an idea. There is no need to create your own web request, simple get the page using the Url. For simulating a click you only have to call the click method on the element. This will simulate all the javascript events also.

Answer (score 0):

You are loosing your result, because

```
page.executeJavaScript(jsScript);
```

returns a [ScriptResult](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/ScriptResult.html), you should do

```
Page newPage = page.executeJavaScript(jsScript).getNewPage();
System.out.println("Result " + newPage);
```